# Report Viewer 2012 (ReportViewer.msi) is not recognizing microsoft system clr types(SQLSysClrTypes.msi) in the system

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

When i try to install ReportViewer 2012 on Windows 2013 server i am getting following error.

[image]

after above error i have installed SqlSysClrTypes 32 and 64 bit versions as shown in below figure.

[image]

after prerequisite installation , i am  still getting the  CLR types for Sql server 2012 error when i try to install report viewer on the server.,

Why Report viewer is not looking into installed prerequisites?

Comment: I did fix this issue from MSDN forum , [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/236f940a-14dc-4493-b9e3-7496afdd5088/report-viewer-2012-reportviewermsi-is-not-recognizing-microsoft-system-clr?forum=sqlreportingservices#236f940a-14dc-4493-b9e3-7496afdd5088). Ran the MSReportViewr using power shell script as admin                                                                                         **Start-Process "C:\Users\Downloads\ReportViewer.msi" /qn -Wait**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sequence,

[image]

the links:

[SQLSysClrTypes.msi](https://www.google.com.sg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiLl_fMpr7PAhUMr48KHbKjA84QFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgo.microsoft.com%2Ffwlink%2F%3FLinkID%3D188392%26clcid%3D0x409&usg=AFQjCNEmw2GK7P9fQve-3X2Z8Gx_7WfRuw&sig2=rrIlXy053W0ig5e5b4Lomw/%22SQLSysClrTypes.msi%22)

[ReportViewer.msi](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/confirmation.aspx?id=35747)

[SSCERuntime_x64-ENU.msi](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=17876)